# Dynamically create associative array with string key and JQuery value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have multiple products on my page and want to create an associative array holding the product number as key and the JQuery element as value so I created this interface

```
interface ProductMap<T extends JQuery> {
    [productNumber: string]: T;
}
```

Then, in my class, I initialize it `protected elements: ProductMap<JQuery> = {};` and want to fill it with data later on

```
const products = $(selector);
if (products.length > 0) {
    $.each(products, function (index, product) {
        this.elements[$(product).data('product-number')] = $(product);
    });
}
```

However, I'm always getting the error

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '{product-number}' of undefined`

How exactly do I create such an associative array?

Comment: Why don't you use a map?

Comment: I read that it only works when compiling in ES6 and we compile in ES5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.elements` is undefined since you change your context using `$.each`. Keep a reference to your instance in order to fix this problem :

```
const products = $(selector);
var self = this;

if (products.length > 0) {
    $.each(products, function (index, product) {
        self.elements[$(product).data('product-number')] = $(product);
    });
}
```

You could also use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks! Everything being a separate context is hard getting used to when coming from other languages. Totally forgot about that again. Thank you

Comment: @Musterknabe If you can use the fat arrow notation `$.each(products, (index, product) => {...});` you might don't need to save the context btw.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze This is still ES6.

Comment: @NathanP. You can write ES6 and compile it as ES5

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze I know, but it seems that it's not something OP wants, as he said in his previous comment.

Comment: @NathanP. I don't interpret like it's something he does not want. And anyways he does not have to do it it just should be a hint that it is possible.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer guys. We are writing ES6 and compiling it to ES5, but I'm a backend guy, so I don't know of all best practices yet. So I should use ` =>` instead?

Comment: @Musterknabe Yes, it'll make your code more readable and maintainable. If you do so, you can forget about keeping `this` reference, since arrow function don't create a new context.